# WebIDL: Generating HTML5 documentation

Tags: javascript, w3c

I am looking to generate a specification (not w3c) of Javascript APIs. If I create webidl for the Javascript APIs, is there a tool that can generate HTML or PDF document out of it? I looked at Respec.js. However that is specific to W3C. Is there any other tool out there, which can take WebIDL and generate a documentation for Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

WebIDL to PDF converters are a rare breed but it certainly is possible to write one.

Biggest part of it would probably be the parser. Fortunately there are some implementations of it:

- [Mozilla WebIDL parser](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/bindings/parser/WebIDL.py), written in Python.
- [WebIDL parser for Javascript](https://github.com/darobin/webidl.js), written in Javascript.

The only thing missing is PDF output.